# Does the left-hand limit of the unit tangent to a non-regular curve exist?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $ \gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ be a  $ C^1 $-curve which is regular, that is $ \gamma'(t) \neq 0 $, except in $ t= 1 $ , that is $  \gamma'(1) = 0 $. Does the left-hand limit of the unit tangent to $ \gamma $ exist, that is does $ \lim_{t\nearrow 1} \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\vert \gamma'(t)  \vert} $ exist?

If $ C^1 $ is not sufficient, which type of differentiability would be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible example in $\mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$.
Define $\gamma(t) = (1-t)^2\exp(i/(1-t))$, $t \in [0,1)$, with $\gamma(1) = 0$.
This is a spiral:
[image: spiral]
Then $\gamma'(1) = 0$ but $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 1^-}\frac{\gamma'(t)}{|\gamma'(t)|}$ does not exist.

....

Variant example:
$$
\gamma_1(t) = \begin{cases}\exp\frac{i-1}{(1-t)},\quad &t<1
\\
 0, \quad &t\ge 1\end{cases}
$$
All properties given above, plus $\gamma_1$ is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I don't think that this example is valid. By the product rule we have $ \gamma'(t) = -2(1-t)\exp(\frac{i}{1-t}) + i\exp(\frac{i}{1-t})$ and this term doesn't converge to zero. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: The function $\gamma$ is differentiable at every point, including $1$, but $\gamma'$ is not continuous at $1$.  Do you intend to require that $\gamma'$ be continuous at $1$?  Perhaps define "smooth" and "regular" so it is clear what is required.

Comment: Variant example added.  Now $\gamma_1$ converges to $0$ much faster, along with all its derivatives.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Since $ \gamma_1 $ is $ C^{\infty} $ it is rectifiable. But the image looks like a infitley long spiral. How can it have finite length..?

Comment: They spiral $\gamma_1$ goes around the origin infinitely many times, but the total length is finite.